# FCC ASR - Strucht Incorrect?

Tags: geospatial, data.gov, fcc

The strucht on the FCC's GIS tower information seems way off? Most of the cell towers are only 50-60' when they are clearly over 100' when you inspect them.

What is the StucHt information based on? Do I need to base it on some calculation like add 100' or something?

Comment: I had a poke around for some metadata but it seems to be missing, is it possible that the height is in metres? You may have to contact the FTC to find out